# Get and set preference values

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

My objective is manage my custom preferences. For this, I have the following code:

***MainActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnTouchListener, GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener, LocationListener, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener{

             public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();

                if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                    launchPreferences(null);
                    return true;
                }

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
            public void launchPreferences(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(this, Preferences.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
    }
```

***Preferences.java***

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

        updatePreference();


    }
```

***settings.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="@+id/preferencias_principal" >
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="@+id/perimer"
        android:title="Perimeter to list"
        android:summary="Maximum distance to list"
        android:defaultValue="2"/>
    <ListPreference
        android:key="@+id/leguage"
        android:title="Lenguage"
        android:summary="What language would you apply?"
        android:entries="@array/lenguage"
        android:entryValues="@array/lenguageva"
        android:defaultValue="1"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

***arrays.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="lenguage">
        <item>English</item>
        <item>Basque</item>
        <item>Spanish</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="lenguageva">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="number">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>5</item>
        <item>6</item>
        <item>7</item>
        <item>8</item>
        <item>9</item>
        <item>10</item>
        <item>11</item>
        <item>12</item>
        <item>13</item>
        <item>14</item>
        <item>15</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

I want to get the values of this preference, using this code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Integer peri = sharedPref.getInt("@+id/perimer", 1);
Integer leng = sharedPref.getInt("@+id/leguage", 2);
```

But this code return default values, *peri=1 and leng=2*.

Not only that, sometimes the information added by the preference activity is changed/deleted or in the ListPreference item is not appear the default item selected (as you can be seen in the image).

[image: Interface result]

When I execute the code visible [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44110120/1508925), with debugger, this is the result:

[image: Debugger result]

What can I do?

Thank you!

Comment: Check my answer below. Hope you will understand about the appropriate use of SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is the KEY `@+id/perimer` and `@+id/leguage` that you used for your `EditTextPreference` and `ListPreference`.

`SharedPreferences` is unable to recognize it as preference `KEY`. As you added resource prefix `@+id`, its treated as `int` resource `id` that's why still it works with below lines but doing abnormal behavior and giving you incorrect output.

```
    Integer peri = sharedPref.getInt("@+id/perimer", 1); // WRONG
    Integer leng = sharedPref.getInt("@+id/leguage", 2); // WRONG
```

**SOLUTION:**

**1.** Do not use resource prefix `@+id` with preference `KEY`. Update your `settings.xml` as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="perimer"
        android:title="Perimeter to list"
        android:summary="Maximum distance to list"
        android:defaultValue="2"/>
    <ListPreference
        android:key="leguage"
        android:title="Lenguage"
        android:summary="What language would you apply?"
        android:entries="@array/lenguage"
        android:entryValues="@array/lenguageva"
        android:defaultValue="1"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

**2.** Get preference values using `SharedPreferences.getString(KEY_NAME, DEFAULT_VALUE)`.

```
    // Get current values
    String peri = mSharedPreferences.getString("perimer", "1");
    String leng = mSharedPreferences.getString("leguage", "2");
```

**3.** Add `OnPreferenceChangeListener` to your `preferences` to get the updated `values` and update the preference `summary` if needed.

```
    // Required to get the updated value and update summary when you input distance
    mPreferencePerimer.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
            String peri = value.toString();

            //Update premier summary
            mPreferencePerimer.setSummary(peri);

            return true;
        }
    });

    // Required to get the updated value and update summary when you change language from list
    mPreferenceLeguage.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {

            String leng = value.toString();
            int lengIndex = Integer.parseInt(leng) - 1;

            // Update leguage summary
            mPreferenceLeguage.setSummary(mPreferenceLeguage.getEntries()[lengIndex]);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

**Here is the full code:**

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {

    // Preference Keys
    public static final String KEY_PREF_PERIMER = "perimer";
    public static final String KEY_PREF_LEGUAGE = "leguage";

    // Shared preference
    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

    EditTextPreference mPreferencePerimer;
    ListPreference mPreferenceLeguage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

        // Shared preference
        mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

        // Perimer
        mPreferencePerimer = (EditTextPreference) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(KEY_PREF_PERIMER);
        // Leguage
        mPreferenceLeguage = (ListPreference) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(KEY_PREF_LEGUAGE);

        // Get current values
        String peri = mSharedPreferences.getString(KEY_PREF_PERIMER, "1");
        String leng = mSharedPreferences.getString(KEY_PREF_LEGUAGE, "2");
        int lengIndex = Integer.parseInt(leng) - 1;

        // Set preference summary
        mPreferencePerimer.setSummary(peri);
        mPreferenceLeguage.setSummary(mPreferenceLeguage.getEntries()[lengIndex]);

        // Required to get the updated value and update summary when you input distance
        mPreferencePerimer.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
                String peri = value.toString();

                //Update premier summary
                mPreferencePerimer.setSummary(peri);

                return true;
            }
        });

        // Required to get the updated value and update summary when you change language from list
        mPreferenceLeguage.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {

                String leng = value.toString();
                int lengIndex = Integer.parseInt(leng) - 1;

                // Update leguage summary
                mPreferenceLeguage.setSummary(mPreferenceLeguage.getEntries()[lengIndex]);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

DEFAULT STATE

[image]

AFTER CHANGE

[image]

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar to this and I think this should work. But this code is untested and may throw some error.

```js
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity implements android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {
private ListPreference lang_list;    

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    // get the stored (or default) value (the index of the selected item)
    Integer leng = sharedPref.getInt("@+id/leguage", 2);

    // get the reference of the ListPreference defined in settings.xml
    lang_list = (ListPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("@+id/leguage");
    // set the selected value
    lang_list.setValueIndex(leng);
    // add a listener to get the changes made by the user. Your Preferences class should implement the OnPreferenceChangeListener interface
    lang_list.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
  }

  ...

  /// When the user selects an item from the list, this function will be fired
  public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
    String key = preference.getKey();
    // ensure that the change has been in the language list
    if (key.equals(lang_list.getKey())) {
      SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      // set the value for the key "@+id/leguage"
      sharedPref.putInt("@+id/leguage", (int) newValue);
      // save the sharedPref object to the file system
      sharedPref.apply();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

UPDATED 2017/06/09: Your Preferences class must implement the android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener interface in order to work with the line `lang_list.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);`

Comment: The lang_list is a private value, is not it? In the other hand, in this part of the code `lang_list.setValueIndex (leng);`, I have an error with _lang_list_ value, because it is null and when `lang_list.setValueIndex (leng);` is executed, the application closes.

Comment: lang_list is a member of the class `private ListPreference lang_list;`. You are getting the NullReference error, because there is no ListPreference with key `leguage`, it should be `lang_list = .....findPreference("@+id/leguage");` because that's the `android:key` value in settings.xml

Comment: Using the laste code I can see lang_list is null, as you can see in the post.

Comment: What code are you executing exactly? Did you insert your initial <code>super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

        updatePreference();</code> in the code I gave you? The '...' of my 'onCreate' function means you have to put your previous code there. The null value seems that there is no preferences loaded.

Comment: Is the same code I posted, with a little change realized without importance.